# How to change label to layout as same as show Notification on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I display `label` on screen, but string of `label` is too long, it hidden a part of  my screen. I want custom or replace `label` to layout as same as `Local Notifications` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications#expanded-layouts)

[image: Local Notifications]

How to collapse `long string` to `short string` with " `...`" ?

I am using Xamarin Forms version 3.4.

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LineBreakMode` Property of Label like.

```
var lblDetail = new Label
    {
        LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
        Text = "a really long string that should show 2 lines then ..."
    };
```

Comment: How to know `string.Length` < 1 lines? (Because I wan't hide button `more` when `string.Length` < 1 lines).

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen what length ? you just need to access it by using lblDetail.Length

Comment: It's length of Text that display on Label, how to know length of it < 1 lines? (I'm testing on device Iphone 8 plus)